# Store data into a column that is an alias mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

Is there a way to store data into a column that is an alias? This column will be used to total sales but will not actually be an existing column in the mysql table. In other words, my table will not have a column to store total sales, i need to make this on the fly as an alias column, where i subtract data in my over head costs column to my product sales column to get the number for total sales and store it in this column that is not actually in my table.

Comment: Like what? Can you show the existing table structure as a table structure with the alias?

Comment: If the column doesn't actually exist, what would it even mean to store something in that column?

Comment: You will need to calculate each time... based on the data you already have... you could create a function that do that and instantiate it each time you need it... but it will be better to add the column to the table

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about the meaning of the verb 'to store'

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, the answer is yes you can do that, but like some good fellas in the comments already mentioned it is not the best way to go about it.

let's say your SELECT query is as follows

```
SELECT id, sales, overhead FROM table_name
```

you can then modify it like this

```
SELECT id, sales, overhead, sales-overhead AS alias_name FROM table_name
```

this will give you also another column called "alias_name" which will hold the value of sales-overhead for each row in the table.

Edited: In my opinion it would make sense to store the calculated values in a new column if number of reads are (much?) larger than number of writes. I am guessing with a simple operation like addition/substraction it would not bring a substantial performance improvement (if at all), but with complex operations it should.

Comment: Last line: No it doesn't

Comment: why not? I did not run any tests so i can't back that theory up, but i could imagine calculating the difference once and then reading it from db vs. calculating it every time you want to read it should in most cases be faster just to read. 
or?
also maybe the difference in this case is not big, but the more complex the operation you are doing the bigger the difference

Comment: So test it. Or don't make the claim!

Comment: I agre with that policy, so I changed the answer to state that it is only my opinion and if/when I do make the tests, I will update it to include that in.